# What does the questions counter show in the Questions tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

At the questions side a questions counter is on the right next to "Ask question" box.

What does this number indicates? Is it how many questions are in total on the site? Or is it how many questions are not answered at the moment?

If it is not the latter, maybe a second counter that shows how many questions are answered would be a nice to have. Like one counter showing: 14.633.535 questions of which are 10.000.000 answered.

Comment: it shows the total number of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq). And if you want to know how many are [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A1) a search will reveal that statistic. No need to put that somewhere prominent.

Comment: did this help you https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Comment: @SagarV I do not really know what to do with this site, sry

Comment: @Kev1n91 the site pointed by Sagar V shows you what you asked for, the number of questions and answers for each StackExchange sites, and other stats.

Comment: @Kev1n91 it shows the percentage of answered questions and other stats

Answer (score 1):

The number shows the number of questions that are in your current filter.  It also has a text indicator underneath the numbers that may help with this.

For example, upon first going to the questions page, it is unfiltered, and currently shows me "31,692 Questions" (specifically, on StackOverflow meta, in this case).  If I click the "unaswered" box just to the left of that, it switches to "6417 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers".  If I reset to "all questions", then filter by the "[jobs]" tag, it says "1090 questions tagged", etc.